# PLSQL_trigger duplicate a# has errors

Tags: plsql

I created this trigger that prevents duplicate acct# to be added. But when I tested the trigger by inserting a duplicate acct#, I got error

> UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (JL.PK.ACCOUNT) VIOLATED

Please help.

```
create or replace trigger update_acct#
    before insert or update on ACCOUNT
    for each row
    declare
        v_cta# NUMBER;

    begin
        select count(A#) into v_cta# from account where A#=:new.A#;
        if v_cta#>1 then  
           raise_application_error (-20105, 'DUPLICATE ACCOUNT NUMBER');
        end if;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger did not throw the error. It didn't even fire.

You did not post the table definition from the error provided but it looks like the column A# in define as the primary key. When you attempted to insert the duplicate row the error was thrown as the PK was validated. You do not have to check primary key for duplicates: Oracle guarantees it is unique.

Further had you trigger fired you would have gotten a "ORA-04091 table Name is mutating ... " error. You cannot reference the triggering table within a row level trigger.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!! I don't understand "You cannot reference the triggering table within a row level trigger."

Comment: The trigger fires on insert or update of ACCOUNT table. So within that trigger you cannot select from the ACCOUNT,  There is an exception for insert into table (column) values( .... ) and Oracle can guarantee it;s a single row.

Answer (score 1):

You should if condition:

```
--old code
if v_cta#>1 then  
           raise_application_error (-20105, 'DUPLICATE ACCOUNT NUMBER');
end if;

--new code
if v_cta#>0 then  
     raise_application_error (-20105, 'DUPLICATE ACCOUNT NUMBER');
end if;
```

When v_cta# equals 1 then your condition will not work